# Python: what is the best way to store numerical key value pairs?

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, hash, hashmap

I have data which consist of numerical keys and values.
I need to increase all keys and values by N number.
While i am using dictionaries for big amout of data my code works very slow.
What is the best way to store this data and the best way to increase values of pairs?

Example:

```
N=2
{1:4,3:6,2:1}
```

expected result:

```
{3:6,5:8,4:2}
```

Thanks

Comment: Pleas share an example and the expected output

Comment: Your question is to broad, the data structure, if exists, will depend in your use cases. For instance do you plan to access The *data structure* by key? In your particular case a [pandas.Series](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html) seems appropriate.

Comment: Thank You for your answer. i need way with the best performance.

Comment: @AvoAsatryan What they told you above is that 'best performance' depends on the set of operations that you need from the storage. Which operations are going to be done more frequently, many many times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can not actually do something faster if you want to change the whole data of dictionary. Even If someone run a for loop we are not sure of O(N) complexity because there can be re-hashing operations internally.

Best thing is you can smartly use one extra variable in memory for updates.

Like initially

del=0 and d={1:4,3:6,2:1}
when you want to increase values and keys by N
update `del+=N`

While retrieving from dictionary for key value k 
Use `d[k-del]+del`

Answer (score 0):

Best you can do about this is `O(N)` whichever data structure you use, you will have to visit the values of each element and increment them.